# How to know if a particular task inside a queue is complete?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a doubt with respect to python queues.

I have written a threaded class, whose  run() method executes the queue.

```
  import threading
  import Queue

  def AThread(threading.Thread):
     def __init__(self,arg1):
         self.file_resource=arg1
         threading.Thread.__init__(self)
         self.queue=Queue.Queue()

     def __myTask(self):
         self.file_resource.write()
         ''' Method that will access a common resource
          Needs to be synchronized.
          Returns a Boolean based on the outcome
         '''

     def run():
         while True:
             cmd=self.queue.get()
             #cmd is actually a call to method
             exec("self.__"+cmd)
             self.queue.task_done()


 #The problem i have here is while invoking the thread
 a=AThread()
 a.queue.put("myTask()")
 print "Hai"
```

The same instance of AThread (a=AThread()) will load tasks to the queue from different locations.

Hence the print statement at the bottom should wait for the task added to the queue through the statement above and wait for a definitive period and also receive the value returned after executing the task.

Is there a simplistic way to achieve this ?. I have searched a lot regarding this, kindly review this code and provide suggessions.

And Why python's acquire and release lock are not on the instances of the class. In the scenario mentioned, instances a and b of AThread need not be synchronized, but myTask runs synchronized for both instances of a as well as b when acquire and release lock are applied.

Kindly provide suggestions.

Comment: Why is there a queue in each thread?

Comment: I have modified the code now. It would not be appropriate for  a=Athread("a.txt") waiting for b=AThread("b.txt") as their call to myTask method will be on 2 different files. Hence Athread("a.txt") will be called only once and all other call to myTask will go into the queue.

Comment: Not used threading much but usually the queue is global and holds the tasks to be done. There is a thread pool (A queue of threads) which holds the threads. A thread manager will loop till task queu is not empty - It will wake up, pull a task from task_queue, pull a thread from thread pool. Assign task to thread. Go to sleep. If no thread exists in thread pool, it will sleep and try again. The thread on its part - After executing and returning the result will add itself to the thread pool. Threads will work independent of each other but the program will not exit till all tasks are done.

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of approaches you could take, depending on the particular contours of your problem.

If your `print "Hai"` just needs to happen after myTask completes, you could put it into a task and have myTask put that task on the queue when it finishes. (if you're a CS theory sort of person, you can think of this as being analogous to continuation-passing style).

If your `print "Hai"` has a more elaborate dependency on multiple tasks, you might look into futures or promises.

You could take a step into the world of Actor-based concurrency, in which case there would probably be a synchronous message send method that does more or less what you want.

If you don't want to use futures or promises, you can achieve a similar thing manually, by introducing a condition variable. Set the condition variable before myTask starts and pass it to myTask, then wait for it to be cleared. You'll have to be very careful as your program grows and constantly rethink your locking strategy to make sure it stays simple and comprehensible - this is the stuff of which difficult concurrency bugs is made.

The smallest sensible step to get what you want is probably to provide a blocking version of Queue.put() which does the condition variable thing. Make sure you think about whether you want to block until the queue is empty, or until the thing you put on the queue is removed from the queue, or until the thing you put on the queue has finished processing. And then make sure you implement the thing you decided to implement when you were thinking about it.

Comment: I am just wondering, what actually is the benefit i am gaining from Queue. I feel i can achieve this through python lists. It could have been useful had a method queue.iscomplete(task) return bool been provided.

Comment: Is queue.put() threadsafe? is list.append()? I don't know the answer to either of those questions, but if the first is yes and the second is no, then that's a benefit right there. The other benefit is in performance: a queue should perform well when you add stuff to one end and take stuff off the other end, but if you use a list for that there's going to be a lot of copying going on (either moving all existing elements forwards on insert or moving all elements backwards on delete).